# Does Paw for Teams have a concept like local Environment variables?

Tags: paw-app

We're trying to get up and running on Teams, but running into some roadblocks about how to properly share stuff with each other.

Specifically, we have some important variables that vary from person-to-person on the team, such as their development hostname, or their credentials (login, password, OAuth tokens, etc).

It looks like if we create those in 'Environments' as dynamic values, then those values will get committed back to the repo?  In which case, everyone in the company will suddenly start using someone else's development hostname?  (Not to mention we don't want to share credentials with each other, etc).

Are we doing it wrong?  How can we share Environments, Groups, Requests, etc without sharing per-person unique data?

Comment: Currently not, we are planning on having this and having local secure values. Most likely the latter will be first to be released as it has less issues with merges etc.